# Reference Path On Another Server on Network C#

Tags: c#, file, network-programming, server

I am having an issue trying to reference a drive\path on another on the same network as my application.

```
string LocationPath = "\\servername\F$\FirstDirectory\SecondDirectory\filename.txt";
```

I would like to use streamreader to capture the contents of this file but can't seem to access it.  This is how I reference the directory in file explorer, how can it be done in C#?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: did you give access to folder/File for Network User/IIS Users

Comment: I am/visual studio/application is in the network, if I type \servername\F$\FirstDirectory\SecondDirectory\filename.txt with two backslashes to start in the file explorer it can find the file.  But programmatically I am not able to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
string LocationPath = "\\\\servername\\F$\\FirstDirectory\\SecondDirectory\\filename.txt";
```

Or use a verbatim string:

```
string LocationPath = @"\\servername\F$\FirstDirectory\SecondDirectory\filename.txt";
```

Comment: The verbatim string you provided is exactly the string I used.

Comment: I had the proper solution, I must've had the directory wrong.  Sorry guys.  But the  correct answer is this one for future reference